# Template Overriding using a customization section

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am trying to override my default templates from customization section, I am using code to do that, but if I am using it I am unable to assign a template to the edit-page   page, Can anyone give an idea how both the customization section and edit-page assign template work. I want to set the template when I am creating a page and after assigning it  I want to override. 
Consider I have a blog page, I want to assign it archive.php template and ten want to override It from customization section. There is the particular condition where I want it to work.

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Adds the Customize page to Select template For Pages
     */

    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cur_page_template' );
function cur_page_template(){
    var_dump( get_option('current_page_template') );
    var_dump( get_page_template() );
    exit;
}
 function widgetsite_template_override($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'template_options', array(
        'title' => __( 'Template Options', 'widgetsite' ),
        'description' => $description, // Include html tags such as <p>.
        'priority' => 160, // Mixed with top-level-section hierarchy.
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_section('theme_template_override', array(
        'title'    => __('Override  Templates', 'widgetsite'),
        'panel' => 'template_options',
        'description' => '',
        'priority' => 120,
    ));


    $templates = get_page_templates();

    $cats = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($templates as $template_name => $template_file){
        //$cats[$template_name] = $template_name;   
        if (strpos($template_file,'layouts') !== false) {
            $cats[$template_file] = $template_name;
        }
    }


    $wp_customize->add_setting('widgetsite_archive_template');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('widgetsite_page_template');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('widgetsite_index_template');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('widgetsite_post_template');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('widgetsite_search_template');

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_archive_template', array(
        'settings' => 'widgetsite_archive_template',
        'label'   => 'Override Archive Template:',
        'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices' => array_merge(array( "archive.php"=>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_page_template', array(
        'settings' => 'widgetsite_page_template',
        'label'   => 'Override Page Template:',
        'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices' => array_merge( array( "page.php" =>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_index_template', array(
        'settings' => 'widgetsite_index_template',
        'label'   => 'Override Index Template:',
        'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices' => array_merge(array( "index.php"=>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_post_template', array(
        'settings' => 'widgetsite_post_template',
        'label'   => 'Override Post Template:',
        'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices' => array_merge(array( "post.php"=>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_search_template', array(
        'settings' => 'widgetsite_search_template',
        'label'   => 'Override Search Template:',
        'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
        'type'    => 'select',
        'choices' => array_merge(array( "search.php"=>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)
    ));

}
add_action('customize_register', 'widgetsite_template_override');

$theme_mode_templates['archive.php'] = get_theme_mod("widgetsite_archive_template");
$theme_mode_templates['page.php'] = get_theme_mod("widgetsite_page_template");
$theme_mode_templates['index.php'] = get_theme_mod("widgetsite_index_template");
$theme_mode_templates['post.php'] = get_theme_mod("widgetsite_post_template");
$theme_mode_templates['search.php'] = get_theme_mod("widgetsite_search_template");


function widgetsite_template_redirect($template){

    global $wp_query;
    global $post;
    $cur= basename($template);
    if(  $cur === 'page.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_page_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
        $template=  get_template_directory() . '/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_page_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
        //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
    }
    if(  $cur === 'archive.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_archive_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
        $template=  get_template_directory() . '/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_archive_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
        //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
    }
    if(  $cur === 'index.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_index_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
        $template=  get_template_directory() . '/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_index_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
        //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
    }
    if(  $cur === 'post.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_post_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
        $template=  get_template_directory() . '/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_post_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
        //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
    }
    if(  $cur === 'search.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_search_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
        $template=  get_template_directory() . '/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_search_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
        //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
    }
    return $template;


}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'widgetsite_template_redirect', 99 );
```

Comment: still not found if it is working correctly , still working on it.on some circumstance It is not working and on  some It is working.

Comment: what instances is it not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. How the choose template box works from post edit screen.

It is important to remember pages are also posts and all meta relating to posts are stored in the post meta table. Page post types differ slightly from the standard post types as they do not follow the `single-postname.php` template use function. Instead pages save the template file path in the `wp_postmeta` database table with a key of `_wp_page_template`.

So one option to change this value is to change it after save post.

```
function save_template_file( $post_id ) {

    if ( 'page' != $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    //insert logic here
    $filelocation= 'anywhere.....';

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', $filelocation);

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_template_file', 11 );
```

Now this is not what you are looking for, but you mentioned you wanted to understand the process, so for pages, wp will reference the template file from post meta and pull this value. So you can change it after saving if it will always follow the same logic (slightly optimized the process). This is the file that shows up in the edit post screen and will always pull the db value unless wp tries to load the template and realizes it does not exist anymore, in which case it reverts to the defaults file in the select box.

2. The filter `template_include` is within the function that searches for the correct template for the pages post type (other post types have the filter `single_template`)

Your use of include here is incorrect. Don't forget a filter will expect a value returned to work correctly in this case `$template`.

So if we want to change the template for pages....

```
add_filter('template_include', 'assign_new_template');

function assign_new_template ($template){

 //we already have a template name, no need to pull it again..
 $cur= basename($template);

 if(  $cur === 'page.php' && get_theme_mod("widgetsite_page_template")){  //note $cur will never be empty!
    $template=  get_template_directory() . '/layouts/' . get_theme_mod("widgetsite_page_template");// assuming this will return correct template...
    //if issues try hardcoding a path to test...
 }

// dont need a else, we will only change the template if our logic is satisfied...

// etc

return $template;
}
```

3. Setting the selects

You are missing the value for default so i propose the following mod as i cant see what your setting in `get_option('current_page_template')` but if there is a correct filename there replace `page.php` with it.

While you are not setting a default value for your select box, your page will render the 1st value of the select if none are marked selected so it should work the same.

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'widgetsite_search_template', array(
    'settings' => 'widgetsite_search_template',
    'label'   => 'Override Search Template:',
    'section'  => 'theme_template_override',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'choices' => array_merge(array("page.php"=>'default'), $cats)
 ));
```

If you resave all the options like above it should be working (it was for me)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think there is some other problem in the code I am getting error `Warning: include(E:\projects\wamp\www\widgetsite/wp-content/themes/widgetsite/layouts/default)` so, can you please find out where I am getting this ?

Comment: `Warning: include(E:\projects\wamp\www\widgetsite/wp-content/themes/widgetsite/layouts/default): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\projects\wamp\www\widgetsite\wp-includes\template-loader.php on line 75` this is the error I think the default template in selectbox is causing problem, can you suggest what I can do with that ?

Comment: does the file exist in that location? it is missing the extension in anycase but the files in the drop down box would not be missing that. It is a mod you made yourself, did you forget to put the extension on somewhere?

Comment: `'choices' => array_merge(array("default"=>get_option('current_page_template')), $cats)` this is the line where problem is existing .but changing it to even `index.php ` I am getting same error .

Comment: See its hard for me to debug what way you have created the select box it should be saving `xxx.php` as the 'current_page_template` option. But changing it manually to index.php will look for index.php in the layouts folder (assuming you have not changed the code format i gave you). Have you got access to the db to check the value in current page template? BTW...you know each `get_option('current_page_template')` will always be the same?

Comment: for every page `template get_option(  'current_page_template' )`  gives `Default Template`  string.

Comment: what is the string its returning? as i said before this is the issue!

Comment: but that is not a filename?

Comment: yeh, that is what I am surprised to see, for every template It is displaying "Default Template" and not the name of the template, but more over we need the path of current template as value of select option or we need something else, as what it display in webpage, that is `current_page_template` that has nothing to do with our target, I was expecting it to return the template name , but did not happened .

Comment: I am uploading the new code , please check it and I now there is no error, but It is not working some times and some times working, what I want to say is there is some exception.

Comment: is it the index.php that is not working? this could be home.php either.. to debug `echo $cur` and echo template to see if the if logic has been matched if that makes sense?

Comment: Now, overriding is not working totally with the recent code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92543/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-david).