# Add back-end WP plugin to front-end template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just need to be pointed the right direction here, I don't expect the exact answer.

Basically, I got a wordpress plugin for woocommerce. It adds a new metabox with options to choose from within the 'add new product' area in admin back-end.

Plugin here https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-incremental-product-quantities/

My theme with other plugins allow me to add new products from the front-end and so I would like to use this plugin also from the front-end.

So how can I bring the plugin to my theme template to be able to choose its option from the front-end? Or what steps to take that I could google some tutorials and take it from there?

I haven't tried anything just yet, I just have no idea where to start.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you want to do things on customization section http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858489/template-overriding-using-a-customization-section may help you.

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for I think, but thanks. I'm just looking through the plugin files and it has a file with the codes to add the metabox onto the admin. So can I use the same codes to add to the theme template?